# retrieving a nested div using cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I want to iterate through each <class='resource-user"> and check if the anchor tag inside the <class='fc-event-container'> has [data.resource]='alan.adams'
I am not sure what to do after this step.
Is it possible to do some kind of nested loopping to retrive the .fc-event-container [image]

```
 cy.get(".fc-content-skeleton > table > tbody > tr >.resource-user").then(el=>
        {
            el.each(el=>
                {
                    
                })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `each()` you directly do something like this:

```
cy.get('td.resource-user')
  .find('a.fc-time-grid-event')
  .should('have.attr', 'data-resource', 'alan.adams')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to pick up - the `td` or the `a` - use `filter()` or `find()` respectively

```js
// Find one cell with "alan.adams" inside nested elements
cy.get(".fc-content-skeleton > table > tbody > tr > .resource-user")
  .filter(':has(a[data-resource="alan.adams"])')
  .should('have.length', 1) 
  .should('match', 'td')
  .each($td => {
    console.log($td)
  })

// Find two event links with "alan.adams"
cy.get(".fc-content-skeleton > table > tbody > tr > .resource-user")
  .find('a[data-resource="alan.adams"]')
  .should('have.length', 2) 
  .should('match', 'a')
  .each($a => {
    console.log($a)
  })
```